# Why does process substitution not work in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to comm command in shell script but getting an error:

```
a.sh: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
a.sh: command substitution: line 1: `comm -12 <( sort /home/xyz/a.csv1 | uniq) <( sort /home/abc/tempfile | uniq) | wc -l'
```

snippet of code-

```
temp=`comm -12 <( sort /home/xyz/a.csv1 | uniq) <( sort /home/abc/tempfile | uniq) | wc -l`
echo $temp
```

Comment: have you try to run comm -12 <( sort /home/xyz/a.csv1 | uniq) <( sort /home/abc/tempfile | uniq) | wc -l on command line .

Comment: yes it works fine when i run same command on command line

Comment: Does `sh` not recognize the [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) notation (the `<(  )` notation)?  It might not if it is some other shell than `bash` (say `dash` on Ubuntu).  If you use `bash -x yourscript` does it work?  What do you have as the shebang `#!` line at the top of the script?  Does it work better if you use `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq` (other than you didn't know about the `-u` option)?  Do you use the value stored in `temp` elsewhere in the script — you're just showing minimized code?  You should probably use `$( … )` to run commands rather than back-quotes ```temp=`…` ```.

Comment: jonathan ,my server using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago), i am not able to get your comment is there anything missing from correct or required configuration. I am a bit new to this , would request you to help me for same..thanks in advance.

Comment: i have added #!/bin/bash line at the top of code. No temp variable is initialized and used there only.

Comment: again i have used $(...) but still getting same error.

Comment: please suggest if there is anything can be done upon this error

Comment: edit your question and add some relevant env variables, e.g. add this  `set | grep SH` to the beginning of your script. Also, try `cat -tev a.sh` - for displaying potential invisible (control) characters.

Comment: BASH=/bin/sh
BASHOPTS=cmdhist:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
BASH_ALIASES=()
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_CMDS=()
BASH_LINENO=([0]="0")
BASH_SOURCE=([0]="a.sh")
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="4" [1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu")
BASH_VERSION='4.1.2(1)-release'
CVS_RSH=ssh
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:posix
SHLVL=2
a.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
a.sh: line 3: `temp=$(comm -12 <( sort /home/xyz/a.csv1 | uniq) <( sort /home/abc/tempfile | uniq) | wc -l))'

Comment: getting above output with cat -tev a.sh

Comment: Please paste the code into the question (you can always edit your own question) and format it for legibility.  Thanks!  (Oh, and delete the code-comment afterwards too.)

Comment: You have: `BASH=/bin/sh` in that information; that's worrying!  Use `BASH=/bin/bash` if it is something you have control over.  The base Bash version is 4.1.2 which supports process substitution, which is what you're using, but [POSIX Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode) documents that process substitution is not available.

Comment: you can try ./script , i tried your code it worked. Please try.

Comment: hey it runs .... can some one explains me what is the difference between running script : sh script.sh and ./script.sh waoooo

Comment: When you say `sh script.sh`, you run Bash in POSIX mode where process substitution is not available.  When you say `./script.sh`, your current shell, Bash, runs the command not in POSIX mode and process substitution is available.  `/bin/sh` is effectively a different program from `/bin/bash` — even if it is the same executable, the behaviour is (radically) different.  See my answer and comments for supporting links.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear yet, but the chances are very high that you either have an incorrect shebang line at the top of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or you are using `sh script.sh` instead of `bash script.sh` while testing it, or you have `SHELL=/bin/sh` or something similar set in the environment.  Your failure is on the [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) code.  When Bash is run as `sh` (in [POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html)), then process substitution is not available:

> 30. Process substitution is not available.

You need to write:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=$(comm -12 <(sort -u /home/xyz/a.csv1) <(sort -u /home/abc/tempfile) | wc -l)
echo $temp
```

or even simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

comm -12 <(sort -u /home/xyz/a.csv1) <(sort -u /home/abc/tempfile) | wc -l
```

which will achieve the same effect as the capture followed by the echo.  When testing, use `bash -x script.sh` or `bash script.sh`.

---

#### Deciphering the indecipherable comment

In an indecipherable [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371672/why-does-process-substitution-not-work-in-a-shell-script/31372298#comment50723459_31371672), the information appears to include:

> BASH=/bin/sh
>   BASHOPTS=cmdhist:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progco‌mp:promptvars:sourcepath
>   BASH_ALIASES=()
>   BASH_ARGC=()
>   BASH_ARGV=()
>   BASH_CMDS=()
>   BASH_LINENO=([0]="0")
>   BASH_SOURCE=([0]="a.sh")
>   BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="4" [1]="1" [2]="2" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu")
>   BASH_VERSION='4.1.2(1)-release'
>   CVS_RSH=ssh
>   SHELL=/bin/bash
>   SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:posix
>   SHLVL=2

Note that `BASH=/bin/sh` and `SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:posix`.  Either or both of these might be a major part of the problem.

Comment: yes , again it ran successfully when  used bash -x script.sh

Comment: How can this answer be correct since the question is: "..run with sh instead of bash". This answer describes how to use process substitution when bash is available. The author does not anywhere describe that bash is available. e.g. He might be using bare-bone alpine version.

Comment: @MarinosAn, I [adjusted the questions title](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31371672/4) to match this answer. The title was [previously changed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31371672/3), thus the mismatch. The original question was not about "how does this work with plain sh (i.e. without bash)" but just "why doesn't it work".