# bin sh script - "(" unexpected

Tags: bash, sh

What is wrong with this script?

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.p; do awk -f get_p.awk "$file" > "$file"er; done 

awk -f phase-comp.awk file1 file.per # výpočet fází
paste <(awk '{print $1}' output1) <(awk '{print $2}' file1) > out
```

The error is:

```
5: skript: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

When I write command separately to terminal. It works well. Thank you

Comment: Other dupes: [Doesn't sh support process substitution <(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18631499/3266847), [How to use process substitution in a script run with sh instead of bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31371672/3266847), [sh -c and process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39069179/3266847)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

It means this script is meant to be interpreted by `sh`, but your script uses [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) which is a bash-specific feature. So, you should change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to make your script work.